# Sub-menus abrindo junto

Tags: html, css

Quero que o sub-menu tenha mais uma camada de menu. Fiz o código crente que ia dar certo, porém, ao passar o mouse no primeiro sub-menu do menu (Protetores > Motor), as opções da segunda camada de sub-menu da opção "Farol" estão sendo abertas junto.
Como resolvo isto?

```css
.menu-categories {
  height: 50px;
}

.menu-categories ul {
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
  ;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.menu-categories ul a {
  display: inline-block;
  background: gold;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12pt;
  color: black;
  width: 120px;
  padding: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.submenu-items {
  width: fit-content;
  margin-top: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

.submenu-items li {
  width: fit-content;
  height: fit-content;
  margin-top: 2px;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
}

.submenu-items li a {
  width: 120px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  border-right: solid black 3px;
}

.deep-menu {
  display: none;
  width: 200px;
  height: 5px;
}

.deep-menu ul {
  height: fit-content;
  left: 150px;
  bottom: 50px;
}


/* As caixas do menu, "menu-categories", contém a rolagem, 
e citando a classe "sub-menu items" ela será de rolagem individual */

.menu-categories ul:hover .submenu-items {
  display: block;
}

.submenu-items a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(255, 115, 0);
}

.menu-categories div:hover .deep-menu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-categories">
  <ul><a href="protetor.html">Protetores</a>
    <div class="submenu-items">
      <li><a href="prot-motor.html" title="Protetores de motor">Motor</a></li>
      <div class="deep-menu">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="protetormotorcg" title="Protetor Honda CG">Honda CG 125/150/160</a></li>
          <li><a href="protetormotorxre" title="Protetor Honda XRE">Honda XRE 300</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <li><a href="prot-farol.html" title="Protetores de farol">Farol</a></li>
      <div class="deep-menu">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="protetorfarolfactor" title="Protetor de Farol Factor">Yamaha Factor</a></li>
          <li><a href="proetorfarolcb300" title="Protetor de Farol XRE">Honda CB300</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <li><a href="prot-carenagem.html" title="Protetores de carenagem">Carenagem</a></li>
    </div>
  </ul>
  <ul><a href="escapamento.html">Escapamentos</a>
    <div class="submenu-items">
      <li><a href="competition.html" title="Escapamento Competition">Competition</a></li>
      <li><a href="usaracing.html" title="Escapamento U.S.A. Racing">U.S.A. Racing</a></li>
    </div>
  </ul>
  <ul><a href="capacete.html">Capacetes</a>
    <div class="submenu-items">
      <li><a href="protorkcapacete.html" title="Capacetes Pro Tork">Pro Tork</a></li>
      <div class="deep-menu">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="g6788.html" title="Capacete G6 788">G6 788</a></li>
          <li><a href="newliberty.html" title="Capacete New Liberty Four">New Liberty Four</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Para prosseguir com a dúvida é importante [edit] a pergunta e trocar o código por um [mcve] do problema. Para entender que tipo de pergunta serve para o site e, consequentemente, evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70) e o [Guia de sobrevivência (resumido) do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70).

Answer (score -3, accepted):

O problema está nas classes. Veja que por exemplo:

```
.submenu-items a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(255, 115, 0);
}

.menu-categories div:hover .deep-menu {
  display: block;
}
```

Quando qualquer elemento da classe .submenu-items a ativar o evento hover esse bloco de código vai ser 'executado'. Por isso que, dentro da ul, todas as opções são exibidas, exemplo a ul Protetores. Concluindo, o ideal seria você fazer um código com Javascript para alterar as propriedades CSS de um determinado elemento HTML quando uma determinada ação é executada pelo usuário.

Answer (score -2):

Resolvido.
Criei a função no JS e a citei com ações do mouse no HTML: `onmousemove="mostraSub('sub1')" onmouseleave="escondeSub('sub1')"`.

```js
function escondeSub(sub){
    subfilho = document.getElementById(sub);
    subfilho.style.display = 'none'; 
  }

function mostraSub(sub){
    subfilho = document.getElementById(sub);
    subfilho.style.display = 'block';
}
```

```css
.sub {
    display: none;
    left: 120px;
}
.sub ul {
    display: none;
    list-style: none;
}
.other-menus {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: flex;
    background: gold;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 12pt;
    color:black;
    max-width: 160px;
    margin-top: 3px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.title-sub {
    padding: 0px;
    width: 120px;
    height: 15px;
}
.sub li {
    position: static;
    width: 120px;
    max-height: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.menu-container ul {
    display:inline-block;
    height: 70px;
}
.menu-header {
    background: gold;
}
.menu-categories {
    height: 50px;
}
.menu-categories ul {
    height: 53px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family:helvetica;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: relative;;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
.menu-categories ul a {
    display:inline-block;
    background: gold;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 12pt;
    color:black;
    width: 120px;
    padding: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.submenu-items {
    width: fit-content;
    margin-top: 3px;
    position: absolute;
    display:none;
}
.submenu-items li {
    width: fit-content;
    height: fit-content;
    margin-top: 2px;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
}
.submenu-items li a {
    width: 120px;
    padding: 15px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    text-align:center;
    border-right: solid black 3px;
}
.menu-categories ul:hover .submenu-items {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-categories">
                <ul><a href="protetor.html">Protetores</a>
                        <div class="submenu-items">
                                <div class="other-menus" onmousemove="mostraSub('sub1')" onmouseleave="escondeSub('sub1')">
                                    <a class="title-sub">Motor</a>
                                        <ul class="sub" id="sub1" style="display: none;">
                                            <li><a href="protetormotorcg" title="Protetor Honda CG">Honda CG 125/150/160</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="protetormotorxre" title="Protetor Honda XRE">Honda XRE 300</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                </div>
                                <div class="other-menus" onmousemove="mostraSub('sub2')" onmouseleave="escondeSub('sub2')">
                                    <a class="title-sub">Farol</a>
                                        <ul class="sub" id="sub2" style="display: none;">
                                            <li><a href="protetorfarolfactor" title="Protetor de Farol Factor">Yamaha Factor</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="proetorfarolcb300" title="Protetor de Farol XRE">Honda CB300</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                </ul> 
            </div>
```

Comment: Não é aproximadamente similar [a isso](https://replit.com/@RonaldoVasques/Menu#style.css) que você está tentando fazer? Digo similar e aproximadamente  pois da forma colocada foi uma mudança rápida no seu código com intuito de apenas replicar o comportamento desejado, o que pode ter ocasionado alguns erros de semântica que serão corrigidos caso confirme ser esse o objetivo.

Comment: Augusto, é isso mesmo!
Vi que o <li> não estava envolvendo os itens do deep-menu. Assim refiz o código do menu à partir do 0 até para praticar e entender melhor e funcionou perfeitamente, agora vou apenas refazer o CSS.